# How to write field values to another field - C

Tags: c, field

I need write field values from `moj_array[]` to `input_array[]`... I need do this because `input_array` must be data type of `const int`, so I can not work with this field in my code.

Where is the problem please?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int array_min(const int input_array[], const int array_size);

int main() {
    //uloha-7
    int input_array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    printf("%d\n", array_min(input_array, 5));
    // prints: 1
  
    return 0;
}

//uloha7.1
int array_min(const int input_array[], const int array_size) {
    int i = 0;
    int moj_array[i];
    int velkost;
    moj_array[i] = input_array[i];
    velkost = array_size;

    if (moj_array != NULL) {
        for (int j = velkost-1; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                if (moj_array[i+1] < moj_array[i]) {
                    // swap
                    int tmp = moj_array[i+1];
                    moj_array[i+1] = moj_array[i];
                    moj_array[i] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return moj_array[0];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[image: Code]

Comment: Your compiler notifies an error because of the uninitialized value `i`. Maybe setting `i=0` helps for a start.

Comment: The problem is you should not post pictures of code, but the code itself, either indented by 4-spaces so it formats as code, or your other option is just to past your code in your question and surround it with `\`\`\`c` at top and `\`\`\`` at the bottom -- which will also format it as code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: @KieranD int=0 works, but If i enter some values to array it gives me a bad numbers..Test values: 
`
 int input_array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d\n", array_min(input_array, 5));
    // prints: 1
`
Compilier gives me a number like -5649846

Comment: Your array is of size 0, `int i=0; int moj_array[i];`. And then you're trying to iterate over it.

Comment: @OnlyForFun don't describe your code, but [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: @Shadowchaser so what I should to do?

Comment: What exactly is the `array_min` supposed to do? Find the smallest value in the array?

Comment: Yes find the smallest number in array. @Jabberwocky

Comment: @OnlyForFun if you would need to find the smallest numbers in a list of numbers on a piece of paper, how would you proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting a copy of the array is a very inefficient way to determine its minimum value.

You should just iterate over the array to determine the minimum and return it at the end:

```
// Function array_min: return the minimum value in an array.
//   input_array: a non null pointer to an array of int
//   array_size: the number of entries in the array, must be > 0
int array_min(const int input_array[], const int array_size) {
    int min = input_array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array_size; i++) {
        if (min > input_array[i])
            min = input_array[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```